# GET request succeeds in POSTMAN and Chrome but fails with axios

Tags: node.js, curl, axios, get, cloudflare

I'm trying to get data from GOAT website but I have a problem : GET request succeeds in POSTMAN and Chrome but fails with axios. **('error code: 1020')**.
So I guess it's because of Cloudflare but I would like to know why it works on POSTMAN and how can I do it with axios.
URL :

```
'https://www.goat.com/web-api/v1/product_variants/buy_bar_data?productTemplateId=815559'
```

My code (copied from postman code snippet) :

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://www.goat.com/web-api/v1/product_variants/buy_bar_data?productTemplateId=815559',
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this website is using cloudflare. Try adding headers to your axios request such as:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

let config = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.goat.com/web-api/v1/product_variants/buy_bar_data?productTemplateId=815559',
    headers: {
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"101\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"101\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    }
};

axios(config).then(async (response) => {
    let data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

This should resolve your problem!

Comment: Hey, I still get the same error

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the very same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try below link.

https://ac.cnstrc.com/browse/collection_id/most-wanted-new?c=ciojs-client-2.29.9&key=key_XT7bjdbvjgECO5d8&i=458569db-a102-49fc-8931-c35b20b79029&s=1&page=1&num_results_per_page=100&_dt=1662752559635

API is exposed, you check on chrom dev tools network on XHR requests.

Best,